# Algorithm to calculate automatic adjusted statements according to payment amount

Tags: algorithm, math

Background:
I decided to make a plan to save let´s say 1200 Euros in 6 months.
The problem is that I could not say that I will save 200 per month because sometimes I have to spend more and sometimes I might have a bonus or something.
For example, in the first month I could save only 100 Euros. Thus, I would like to split the remaining 100 in the other 5 remaining months: 20 euros more each month.

**Original plan:**

Jan  |  Feb  |   Mar  |   Apr  |   May  |   Jun

200  |   200  |   200  |   200  |   200  |   200  -> Total is 1200

**Actual plan for the first month**

Jan  |   Feb  |   Mar  |   Apr  |   May  |   Jun

100  |   220  |   220  |   220  |   220  |   220  -> Total is still 1200

Then, on February I got my bonus and could save 300 instead of 220. So now I will divide the extra 80 bucks in the remaining 4 months. Since it was more than I should have saved, now I will subtract. 80/4 = 20

**Actual for the second month:**

Jan  |   Feb  |   Mar  |   Apr  |   May  |   Jun

100  |   300   |  200  |   200  |   200  |   200  -> Total is still 1200

**Question:** What would be the algorithm to automatically adjust the value to be saved for the remaining installments according to the i (month in question), goal (final amount, constant) and amount already deposited?
Is it possible to represent this 3 parameters in a function?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually not an algorithm, it is simple math. Assume that you are on month `i`(a value from 1 to 6) and so far(for months 1, 2... i-1) you've saved X dollars. Then for the remaining months, you need to save `(1200 - X) / (6 - i + 1)`. I divide by `(6 - i + 1)` because this is the number of months from i-th inclusive.